# Why when a constructor is annotated with @JsonCreator, its arguments must be annotated with @JsonProperty?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

In Jackson, when you annotate a constructor with `@JsonCreator`, you must annotate its arguments with `@JsonProperty`. So this constructor

```
public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

becomes this:

```
@JsonCreator
public Point(@JsonProperty("x") double x, @JsonProperty("y") double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

I don't understand why it's necessary. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Jackson has to know in what order to pass fields from a JSON object to the constructor.
It is not possible to access parameter names in Java using reflection - that's why you have to repeat this information in annotations.

Comment: This is not valid for Java8

Comment: @MariuszS That is true but this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32272061/271149) explains how to get rid of extraneous annotations with the help of Java8 compiler flag and a Jackson module. I've tested the approach and it works.

Comment: Ofcourse, works like a charm :) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html

Answer (score 68):

Parameter names are normally not accessible by the Java code at runtime (because it's drop by the compiler), so if you want that functionality you need to either use Java 8's built-in functionality or use a library such as ParaNamer in order to gain access to it.

So in order to not having to utilize annotations for the constructor arguments when using Jackson, you can make use of either of these 2 Jackson modules:

### jackson-module-parameter-names

This module allows you to get annotation-free constructor arguments when using **Java 8**. In order to use it you first need to register the module:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule());
```

Then compile your code using the -parameters flag:

```
javac -parameters ...
```

Link: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/parameter-names

### jackson-module-paranamer

This other one simply requires you to register the module or configure an annotation introspection (but not both as pointed out by the comments). It allows you to use annotation-free constructor arguments on **versions of Java prior to 1.8**.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// either via module
mapper.registerModule(new ParanamerModule());
// or by directly assigning annotation introspector (but not both!)
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new ParanamerOnJacksonAnnotationIntrospector());
```

Link: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base/tree/master/paranamer

Comment: Paranamer module seems to be much better than ParameterNames: it does not require Java 8 and does not require the `-parameters` compiler flag. Are you aware of any downside?

Answer (score 32):

It is possible to avoid constructor annotations with jdk8 where optionally the compiler will introduce metadata with the names of the constructor parameters. Then with [jackson-module-parameter-names](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-parameter-names) module Jackson can use this constructor.  You can see an example at post [Jackson without annotations](https://manosnikolaidis.wordpress.com/2015/08/25/jackson-without-annotations/)

- [The Java™ Tutorials - Obtaining Names of Method Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html)

Comment: deprecated and moved to [jackson-modules-java8/parameter-names](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/parameter-names)

Answer (score 24):

One can simply use java.bean.ConstructorProperties annotation - it's much less verbose and Jackson also accepts it. For example :

```
  import java.beans.ConstructorProperties;

  @ConstructorProperties({"answer","closed","language","interface","operation"})
  public DialogueOutput(String answer, boolean closed, String language, String anInterface, String operation) {
    this.answer = answer;
    this.closed = closed;
    this.language = language;
    this.anInterface = anInterface;
    this.operation = operation;
  }
```

Comment: Very nice catch I couldn't find out otherwise: so, no dependency against Jackson API and way less verbose!

Answer (score 7):

Because Java bytecode does not retain the names of method or constructor arguments.

Comment: Not true anymore: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html

Comment: @MariuszS indeed, but since this is a new (and non-default compiler flag), Jackson will have to continue to to support its `@JsonProperty` annotation

Answer (score 5):

When I understand [this](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_457.html) correctly, you replace the default constructor with a parameterized one and therefore have to describe the JSON keys which are used to call the constructor with.

Answer (score 3):

As precised in the [annotation documentation](https://github.com/codehaus/jackson/blob/master/src/java/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonProperty.java), the annotation indicates that the argument name is used as the property name without any modifications, but it can be specified to non-empty value to specify different name:

Answer (score -1):

Just come across it and got an answer somewhere. you can use below annotation since 2.7.0

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class Point {
    final private double x;
    final private double y;

    @ConstructorProperties({"x", "y"})
    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```