# Must we use @JsonProperty in Scala case classes?

Tags: json, scala, json-deserialization, jackson-modules

everyone.

This seems to be quite an unnecessary exercise to define the @JsonProperty annotations for Json serialization of a case class. For example:

```
case class Foo @JsonCreator()(
  @JsonProperty("a") a: String,
  @JsonProperty("b") b: Boolean,
  @JsonProperty("c") c: Int)
```

It appears that the trivial @JsonProperty annotations like this (just repeating the parameter's name) can be avoided in Java, by using the **jackson-module-parameter-names** module and the **-parameters** javac option:

[Why when a constructor is annotated with @JsonCreator, its arguments must be annotated with @JsonProperty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920367/why-when-a-constructor-is-annotated-with-jsoncreator-its-arguments-must-be-ann/33578478#33578478)

However, that doesn't work with Scala case classes. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Are you using same version of `jackson-module-scala` as `jackson-core`? I believe the use of the annotation is unnecessary when the property name is same as the field name.

Comment: I'm just using the Jackson modules that come with Lagom by default. I'll check. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right. It turns out Lagom doesn't include **jackson-module-scala** by default.