# POST rest entity with custom argument constructor

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm exposing my Entity classes with [spring-data-rest](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) and spring-data-jpa without difining any custom controllers.

```
@Entity
public class Domain {

    @Id
    private String domainName;

    Domain(String name) {
      this.domainName = name;
    }

    private Domain() { }
}
```

Say I want to create a Domain with id `stackoverflow.com`, what should I pass in the request body?

Say the Domain resource is exposed at the endpoint `/domains`. The reason I'm setting @Id to an String is that I want to be able to retrive a domain by `GET /domains/{domainName}`

**Update**

When sending a POST request as follows:

```
POST /domains
{
    "domainName": "stackoverflow.com"
}
```

I get the exception:

> JpaSystemException: ids for this class must be manually assigned
>   before calling save(): space.linuxdeveloper.Network; nested exception
>   is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class
>   must be manually assigned before calling save():
>   space.linuxdeveloper.Network] with root cause

Comment: With no public no args constructor you will most likely need to use Jackson's `@JsonCreator` annotation to handle deserialization. http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_457.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920367/why-when-a-constructor-is-annotated-with-jsoncreator-its-arguments-must-be-ann

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this request body:

```
POST /domains
{
    "domainName": "stackoverflow.com"
}
```

---

Don't forget to correct your c-tor:

```
Domain(String domainName) {
  this.domainName = domainName;
}
```

Comment: this.name in constructor was a typo.