# Spring Rest. Eliminate json property at HTTP.POST

Tags: java, jackson, spring-rest, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm trying to exclude the possibility of a json field to be modificated at HTTP.POST operation. This is my class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserModel {

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private Long userId;

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    private RoleModel role;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String secondName;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String password;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private Date registrationDate;
}
```

I want for example the property **userId** to be accessible only for read (http get).
I've tried with @JsonProperty but it doesn't work, instead it works for the **password** field. (this property is visible only for write/ post).

Can you please tell me where I'm wrong? or if there is a more elegant way to do that?

Many thanks,

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920367/why-when-a-constructor-is-annotated-with-jsoncreator-its-arguments-must-be-ann) should help.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewS, I'm still looking for another solution. As you can see I use lombok and I don't want to write constructors for domain classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve such thing with @JsonView annotation:

```
// Declare views as you wish, you can also use inheritance.
// GetView also includes PostView's fields 
public class View {
    interface PostView {}
    interface GetView extends PostView {}
}

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserModel {

    @JsonView(View.GetView.class)
    private Long userId;

    @JsonView(View.PostView.class)
    @NotNull
    private String username;
    ....
}

@RestController
public class Controller {

    @JsonView(View.GetView.class)
    @GetMapping("/")
    public UserModel get() {
        return ... ;
    }

    @JsonView(View.PostView.class)
    @PostMapping("/")
    public UserModel post() {
        return ... ;
    }

...
}
```

For more information: https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring