# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException when sending a POST request or trying to update

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a Spring application with the following controller:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/office")
public class OfficeController {

    private OfficeRepository officeRepository;

    public OfficeController(OfficeRepository officeRepository){

        this.officeRepository = officeRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<Office> getAll(){
        List<Office> offices = this.officeRepository.findAll();

        return offices;
    }

    @PutMapping
    public void insert(@RequestBody Office office){

        this.officeRepository.insert(office);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public void update(@RequestBody Office office){

        this.officeRepository.save(office);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Office getByIdOffice(@PathVariable("id") String id){
        Office office = this.officeRepository.findById(id);

        return office;
    }

    @GetMapping("/status/{status}")
    public List<Office> getByStatus(@PathVariable("status") String status){
        List<Office> offices = this.officeRepository.findByStatus(status);

        return offices;
    }

    @GetMapping("/floor/{floor}")
    public List<Office> getByFloor(@PathVariable("floor") String floor){
        List<Office> offices = this.officeRepository.findByFloor(floor);

        return offices;
    }
}
```

And secondary class is:

```
public class User {
    //@Id
    //private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // public String getId() {
    //     return id;
    // }

    public String getFirstName() {

        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){

        return lastName;
    }

}
```

However, when I send a POST request from Postman containing :

```
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        Office bir = new Office(
                "2",
                "busy",
                "12/07/2019",
                "20/07/2019",
                Arrays.asList(
                        new User("Jon", "Snow"))
        );
```

I get the following response:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1562918471785,
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
    "message": "Could not read document: Can not construct instance of office.demo.User: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@85534e1; line: 8, column: 17] (through reference chain: office.demo.Office[\"users\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of office.demo.User: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@85534e1; line: 8, column: 17] (through reference chain: office.demo.Office[\"users\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])",
    "path": "/office"
}
```

Also, I was experimenting with Spring Security as well. The server does not show any error and the controller does not seem to receive the request as "inside" is not being printed. I am trying to get acquainted with Spring, however I could not find the reason for such an error. I would be grateful for any help. All other methodes like /all are all working perfectly fine, I tried to make another seeder but that dosen't work to .Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found you have no setters in User class and may be @JsonCreator annotation for the constructor will work. Incase - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920367/why-when-a-constructor-is-annotated-with-jsoncreator-its-arguments-must-be-ann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear, `User` is missing default constructor. If you declare any constructor explicitly then you are responsible for adding No Arg constructor. Because by default jackson uses `setters` and `getters` for serialization and deserialization

```
public class User {
//@Id
//private String id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public User() {
   }

// public String getId() {
//     return id;
// }

public String getFirstName() {

    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName(){

    return lastName;
    }

 }
```